# SSL mutual authentication with pfx certificate and Alamofire Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, mutual-authentication

I've to send a client certificate in PFX format for mutual auth to my server through web request.
I'm using Alamofire 4 with Swift 3, but I can't find a good tutorial to achieve my goal.

Has anyone ever had to deal with this type of problem in the past?

Thanks.

Comment: Where you able to find the solution

Comment: i'm also curious, can't seem to find any solution

Comment: I realise you guys might not need this anymore but someone else might find it useful -I think this might be what you're looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985856/getting-client-certificate-to-work-for-mutual-authentication-using-swift-3-and-a/40408479?noredirect=1#comment100949586_40408479

Comment: For some reason the bounty has been awarded to the wrong answer in the question, Andrew's answer worked for me. It's for P12 files but PFX is essentially the same under the hood so you should be able to just chop off the .pfx and stick .p12 on the end for it to work. It might even take pfx without any changes, idk you'll have to investigate yourself.