# How to store and update .p12 cert in iOS app?

Tags: swift, xcode, keychain, pkcs#12

I'm currently developing an iOS app connecting to a REST API. To secure the access of my API, I use on my server (NGINX) an authentication based on the ssl-client-authentication.

I use a .p12 certificate, and to process the authentication I use the swift code described on the accepted answer in this link ([Getting client certificate to work for mutual authentication using Swift 3 and Alamofire 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985856/getting-client-certificate-to-work-for-mutual-authentication-using-swift-3-and-a)).

Which mean that actually the certificate is store in my projet as resource in the Bundle. So I have several questions about security in iOS and I need advices.

• Is it ok to use a certificate as resource ?

If it is secure to store a certificate as resource.

• What is the best way to store the passphrase for my certificate used in swift code (Xcode Environment Variable, ...) ?

More, I would like to update the certificate when it will be expired by OTA. How this is possible ?

Thank you in advance.